# Совместить один dataframe с другим

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть один датафрейм. Пример его:

```
  col1 col2 
0 x    0
1 y    1
2 z    2
```

Есть второй датафрейм.

```
  col3 col4 
0 y    5
1 z    6
2 x    7
```

Нужно получить нечто такого типа наиболее рациональным способом (не делая долгие циклы и желательно не меняя индексацию):

```
  col1 col2 col4
0 x    0    5
1 y    1    6 
2 z    2    7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.join(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
In [8]: d1
Out[8]:
  col1  col2
0    x     0
1    y     1
2    z     2

In [9]: d2
Out[9]:
  col3  col4
0    y     5
1    z     6
2    x     7

In [10]: res = d1.join(d2[["col4"]])

In [11]: res
Out[11]:
  col1  col2  col4
0    x     0     5
1    y     1     6
2    z     2     7
```